# Login cookies security

Tags: php, security, cookies, authentication

I'm making my first fullout website were users can sign up and log in. Is the following cookies secure? Do I need a more specific random code for the name instead of username or password?

```
setcookie("username", "$username", time()+3600);
setcookie("password", "$password", time()+3600);
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for setting cookies directly instead of using php's session functions?

Comment: "Is putting a plain text password on the wire and in a file on the client secure?" - no, not really. You're not supposed to be storing the plaintext password at all, for that matter.

Comment: Stop what you are doing.   use session_start() and the $_SESSION super global.

Answer (score 1):

Someone could steal the cookie file from your users browser and gain access to his username/password, you do not want that. So you give the user some random auth-token (session id) and associate the user on the serverside with a dataset, containing login information.
Php has that feature already build-in.

So you should use php's session engine instead.
http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

It also kinda handles the problem what happens if your Browser does not support Cookies.

Comment: Also, from Mat's comment, you should NEVER store the password in clear text. You should hash the password (SHA1 for example) and store the hash on the server.

Comment: event if its salted and hashed storing a password in a cookie is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It should be use if users want to remember their login and password to logged them back automatically. If not use sessions.

And the password should be encoded. **Never store the password that someone has typed directly!** 
It's safe if your password is encoded, like :

```
md5('my_password');
```

With this encoding there is no way to decrypt the password because it's linked to an infinity of values.

When you compare the 2 passwords to see if there are the same do this when both password are encoded

Comment: MD5 is considered broken and should not be used for cryptographic purposes.

Comment: It's broken but it's a one way encryption so for password it's fine

Comment: Various flaws have been demonstrated in MD5. There are so many better and readily available hash functions out there, so why on earth would you continue to use/recommend MD5?

Comment: because in for password i think it's still 100% secure, but what other available hash are that easy to use in PHP?

Comment: bcrypt is arguably one of the best ways to securely hash passwords in PHP, and is fairly easy to implement. One problem with hashes such as MD5 is that they are designed for speed, making it easier for attackers to mount an offline brute force attack. The following may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/886994

Comment: Thanks i'll keep that in mind when i'll have to implement an account system next time then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are secure, as they are specific to the computer/browser only. (the cookies).

Time is good, as they auto-delete after an hour.

YES, specify a more random code instead of "username" and "password" for the ID's of the cookies, such as "(nameofsite)usern" and "(nameofsite)pas", as the cookies with the names "username" and "password" may interfere with cookies **already** on the users computer/browser from another website.

I'm assuming you're already encoding your passwords as they are submitted.

Comment: Thank you  for the timely and helpful responce